# Modify search form with plugin

Tags: plugin-development, filters, search

I want to add `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">` to search form for any theme i would use.

I read that i should not modify theme itself but [create a plugin.](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/why-you-shouldnt-use-functions-php/)

So i created the plugin:

```
add_filter('get_search_form', 'my_search_form');
function my_search_form($html) {
 $html ='

 <form role="search" method="get" class="searchform" action="'.esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ).'>
<!--asdf!-->
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="'.esc_attr_x( 'Search &hellip;', 'placeholder', 'estore' ).'" value="'.esc_attr( get_search_query() ).'" name="s">
    <button type="submit" class="searchsubmit" name="submit" value="'.esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button', 'estore' ).'"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>';

 return $html;
}
```

The theme has `searchform.php` with original form and the plugin does not change it.

What should i do?

Comment: So you only want to make the `product` post type searchable on the front-end and not `post` and `page` ?

Comment: @birgire yes, the only difference is that i want to make it via plugin and not hard-code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to only make the `product` post type *searchable*, from a plugin code:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Product Search Only **/

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type )
{
    $args['exclude_from_search'] = true;

    if( 'product' === $post_type && (bool) $args['public'] )
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = false;

    return $args;
}, 999, 2 );
```

Here we modify the post type registration, by setting the `exclude_from_search` to true, for all post types, except the public `product` post type. If needed you can adjust the late priority.